# Combining search, IF and OR in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Have an excel file like this:

armchair    3

wheelchair  1

stool       1

bench       1

sidetable   2

table       0

plate       2

I want to search for multiple part of words, and then return the value in the second column. In this case I want to search for 'chair' and 'table', and also want to have the value returned for armchair etc.
My current statement is this:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("chair";A1));A2;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("table";A1));A2;0))
But this will become really lengthy if you want to search for ten part of words (which is the case). 
Is there a possibility I can integrate the OR statement, in order to easily add part of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the words in a list like this:-

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"chair","table"},A1))),B1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting multiple keys in area I use:

```
=SUMMENPRODUKT(ZÄHLENWENN(A1:A23;B1:B3))
```

`A1:A23` is searching area, `B1:B3` contains the keys to search..

Comment: I don't think that this will solve my problem, because I want to search for part of words and not whole words, and return the value in the second column, not how many cells contain the word.